# How can I see what custom URI schemes are registered?

Tags: macos, omnifocus

One of the neat things about OmniFocus is that you can add tasks to it by calling `omnifocus:///add?name={query}` from a browser, or launcher (like Alfred or LaunchBar). I'd like to know what other functions there are to call for it, and other apps as well.

I poked through the `info.plist` of Package Contents of the app, but it only detailed that `omnifocus://` was indeed registered as a custom scheme. And I couldn't find any reference to it on Omni's site as well.

Comment: While I didn't figure out how to find specific URI schemes, I did solve my problems with an AppleScript that I imported into Alfred.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use RCDefaultApp to manage handlers for protocols and URIs.  There may be a better way to do it programmatically, but [Rubicode's RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) is very useful for a lot of other reasons too.

When you dump the launch services database does it show up there?

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -h
```

Comment: That's definitely nicer than poking through plists, but doesn't quite answer my question :). I don't want to know just what URI schemes are registered, but what functions they'll respond to.

Comment: I added the path of lsregister to my suggestion, maybe the arguments and variables can be mined that way?