# What are all of the URI Schemes Available on macOS

Tags: macos, applications, url

This question comes as an offshoot from this question [Can MacOS Dictionary be invoked by a URI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/397110/119271)

I remembered that there are a number of URI schemes that can utilized in macOS, but I couldn't remember how to list them.  For example, there is `x-man-page://` that allows you to create a link to any particular man page and open it up in a Terminal Window with it's own profile: [How to open the Apple URL protocol x-man-page:// in iTerm and not Terminal (default)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/382301/119271)

This existing question:  [How can I see what custom URI schemes are registered?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51067/119271) relied on a now defunct tool called RCDefault App that would allow you to not only list all available URIs but associate them with any particular app (i.e. `telnet://` with iTerm2)

So, in attempting to answer the question, I couldn't remeber the URI scheme and needed a way to find them. **Is there a way to list all of the registerd URI schemes?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Use `lsregister`

The command can be found in `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister`. I suggest creating a symlink to one of the directories in your PATH for easy access.  You can copy and past the following command for simplicity

```
% sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister /usr/local/bin/lsregister
```

Now, you can run `lsregister` from anywhere.

#### Dump the URL Binding Table

`lsregister` has a number of database tables that contain various application registration details.  The table that we're interested in is `URLSchemeBinding`

```
% lsregister -dump URLSchemeBinding
```

This will give you the full list from `afp://` to `x-man-page://`.

To find the URL scheme used for the dictionary we can `grep` for it:

```
% lsregister -dump URLSchemeBinding | grep "dict*"
dict:               35608 (0x8b18) (0x8b1a)
x-dictionary:       35604 (0x8b14) (0x8b16)
```

Comment: This should be obvious to everyone, but just in case—if you only intend to run this once and would rather not pollute /usr/local/bin, you can just run the command from its original location directly. One fell swoop: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump URLSchemeBinding`

Comment: Alternative approach: `alias lsregister='/System/Library/Frame…/lsregister` in session profile e.g.,`.zshrc`.